# Complex locus plotter online

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, online-resources, locus

I am looking for an online complex locus plotter, which inputs like (for example)$|z|=1, \frac{|z-i+2|}{|z-2i|}=2$.

Prefer not to inputs $x,y$ form.
If you know something on web please guide me to its link.

I tried to use Desmos complex mode but I can't input by the $z$ form.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WLOG $z=\cos t+i\sin t$ eliminate $t$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : Thanks but in which program?

Comment: Why do you "prefer not to inputs $x,y$ form" when that is easy to do in Desmos?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was planning to use $(r,\theta)$ form , not by plotters

Comment: @rschwieb:Because I was teaching very first steps in finding loci, and I want to show to my students that's work.

Comment: If the ultimate goal is for them to be able to graph stuff in the Argand plane, it seems like it would be good to teach them how it translates to a solution in $\mathbb R^2$.  It's not even that hard...

Comment: @Khosrotash Surely they already have experience finding loci in $\mathbb R^2$?  If so, it would make a lot of sense to translate. If not, it does not make much sense to start with loci in $\mathbb C$...  But that's all, I don't mean to badger you. Asking about a complex plotter is fine.  I just thought the X that led to this Y seems like it could use a second consideration.